# jQuery change page-break-inside in to break-inside

Tags: javascript, jquery

First, I apologize for Strange English.

I'm Using Jquery 1.9 With Chrome 70, Extjs 4

I just use jQuery function css() for give 'page-break-inside:avoid'

but element style changed to 'break-inside:avoid'

**try**

```
 $($(tr).find('iframe').contents()).find('table').each(function(index,tableDOM){
        $(tableDOM).css('page-break-inside','avoid');
 });
```

**expected**

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:500px; page-break-inside:avoid">
```

**result**

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:500px; break-inside:avoid">
```

I don't know why this happen. I need 'page-break-inside' not 'break-inside' because evopdf doesn't cognize 'break-inside'

Could I have missed something?

I would appreciate your help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very strange indeed. You can work around it if you manually set the attribute `style` using `.attr()`

```
$(tableDOM).attr('style','page-break-inside:avoid');
```

```js
//$('table').css('page-break-inside','avoid');
$('table').attr('style','page-break-inside:avoid; width:500px;');
```

```css
table
{
border: 1px solid grey;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,th
{
 border: 1px solid grey;
 padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><th>a</th><th>b</th><th>c</th><th>d</th><th>e</th></tr>
  <tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But it remove another `style` property

Comment: @Mohammad then add all other style attributes together

Comment: As you can see in OP table has `width:500px` in style

Comment: @Mohammad Edited my answer. Thanks

Comment: @Ahmad Thanks for nice Answer. still I don't know why 'page-break-inside' change to 'break-inside' but I solved problem. Thank you!